# TypoScript: Text content of current page

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, typo3, typoscript

I am trying to generate the `og:description` tag, required by Facebook, dynamically out of the content of the shown page. My idea is to use the content-text of the page if there is no meta description given. I tried this script:

```
page.headerData.838 = CONTENT
page.headerData.838 {
  table=tt_content
  select {
    where = (CType = "text")
  }
  renderObj=TEXT
  renderObj{
    field=bodytext
    stdWrap.stripHtml=1
    noTrimWrap =|<meta property="og:description" content="|" />| 
  }
}
```

The problem is that this tag not even appears on the page. So what's the catch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

Default Description:

```
page.meta{
  description.field = description
}
```

Description if Default Description is empty:

```
page.meta.description.ifEmpty.stdWrap.cObject = CONTENT
page.meta.description.ifEmpty.stdWrap.cObject {
 table= tt_content
 select {              
   selectFields = bodytext
 }
 renderObj =COA
 renderObj {
   10=TEXT
   10 {
     field = bodytext     
     stripHtml=1
     crop = 300 | ... | 1        
   }
 }
}
```

And og:description:

```
temp.OpenGraphDescription = COA
temp.OpenGraphDescription{
 10=CONTENT
 10.table= tt_content
 10.select {              
   selectFields = bodytext
 }
 10.renderObj =COA
 10.renderObj {
   10=TEXT
   10 {
     field =  bodytext     
     stripHtml=1
     crop = 300 | ... | 1        
   }
 }
 wrap = <meta property="og:description" content="|" />
}
page.headerData.55 < temp.OpenGraphDescription
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using rendering `tt_content` elements as meta tags, it can be tricky as they are RTE fields, so, there is some possibility that will broke your HTML code even with stripHtml.

Instead it's better idea to use `Meta > Description` field of `Page` properties for this task, it's just safer. Note that if you'll use more than one tt_content with Text type on the page, your code will create the same number of `<meta />` tags.

BTW: your snippet is rather correct - it works without any problems, maybe you have some cache issues on some pages?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can just render the content of your middle column, strip HTML and wrap it into og:description? I guess you will have an maximal length of your description.

```
page.headerData.838 < styles.content.get
page.headerData.838.stdWrap {
  stripHtml = 1
  crop = 180 | ... | 1
  wrap = <meta property="og:description" content="|" />
}
```

(untested!)